# What fractions of matter are retained and displaced by quasars?

Tags: black-hole, quasars

Following on from a query concerning [quasar mass](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/26861/quasar-mass-and-accretion-rates), what fraction of matter is ejected compared to matter that is lost to the BH?

Is there a graph that describes the fractions of the mass of quasars which contribute to disk radiation, plume radiation and black-hollowed? (sorry I can't think of a word because accretion and accretion disk is confusing)

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it turns out to be a highly nonlinear relation which depends on initial mass, elapsed time, and so on.